# Convert Date to Timestamp using Shopify Liquid

Tags: date, timestamp, shopify, liquid

I building a template and I want to convert a date to a Timestamp on Shopify.

I know I can convert a timestamp to a date using this:

```
{{ '1560523384' | date: "%d-%m-%Y" }} // result is 14-06-2019
```

But I would like to do the opposite

```
{{ '14-06-2019' | timestamp }} // do not work
```

Anyway to do this using Shopify Liquid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking at is Epoch Timestamp. To get the same use the below code in Liquid templates -

```
var timestamp = "{{ 'now' | date: "%s"}}";
```

This gives the current timestamp in Epoch Format. Here is a link to read more about date formatting in Liquid files - [Link](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/date/)

### Update

Here is an updated answer how to convert a sepcific date to epoch timestamp in shopify liquid code

```
var timestamp = "{{ "March 14, 2016" | date: "%s"}}";
# timespamp —- 1457928000

var timestamp = "{{ "14-06-2019" | date: "%s"}}";
# timespamp —- 1560484800
```

And vice versa from Timestap to Date

```
var _date = "{{ "now" | date: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" }}";
# _date —- 2021-08-24 01:14

var _date = "{{ "1560484800" | date: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" }}";
# _date —- 2019-06-14 00:00
```

You can so forth convert any timestamp in the date format in the above documentation link.

Comment: @Guerrilla The question when asked was regarding “now” timestamp value. However, a generic conversion was missing in the answer. I have added an update. Hope this answers your question.