# How to convert datetime of format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM::SS to epoch timestamp in liquid tags?

Tags: tags, liquid

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56600545/convert-date-to-timestamp-using-shopify-liquid) that below code works for converting date to timestamp in liquid script.

```
var timestamp = "{{ "14-06-2019" | date: "%s"}}";

timespamp —- 1560484800
```

But when I tried this code various online liquid editor, they assume by by default that date is in mm/dd/yyyy format return the respective timestamp or they return the input string if date goes beyond 12.

Adding the screenshot for reference:

[image]

Editor where I am trying this

https://jumpseller.in/support/liquid-sandbox/

https://geekplayers.com/run-liquild-online.html

I want to convert "30/11/2023 4:53:11 AM" to a epoch timestamp. I tried the below code but its not returning the timestamp

```
{{ "30/11/2023 4:53:11 AM" | date: "%s"}}
```

Instead it just returns the input string